# Как использовать несколько слов при использовании полнотекстового поиска postgres?

Tags: postgresql, полнотекстовый-поиск

У меня есть сущность с title: "Тестирование полнотекстового поиска postgres".

Моя цель, что бы при поисковой фразе 'тест поиска' данная сущность находилась.

Запросы ниже бестолковые и ничего не находят.

```
select title from projects where to_tsvector(title) @@ plainto_tsquery('тест поиска')
```

```
select title from projects where to_tsvector(title) @@ plainto_tsquery('тестирование поиска');
```

В какую сторону думать? PostgreSQL может быть умнее при таком поиске?

Comment: второй должен работать… фидл с тестовыми данными в студию…

Comment: и, кстати, [УМВР](http://dpaste.com/2XC9TU2TT)…

Comment: @Fat-Zer да, извините, этот запрос работает. Перепутал с plainto_tsquery('тест поиска'). Не смотря на то, что "тест" входит в "тестирование" - pg не ищет. Это другая опера уже? В какую сторону думать?

Comment: для этого надо указать метчинг префикса… `plainto_tsquery()` этого не умеет, так что как-то так: `to_tsquery('тест:* & поиск')`… искать по паттерну из середины слова с помощью этого не получится и, вероятно, это отразится на скорости…